# Unexpected token error in Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

While executing the below script I am getting error

> token ':' in expression or statement.

I tried putting "=" instead of ":" but no luck. I am not a powershell expert.

Script:

```
 {
     "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
     "name": "az104-08-vm1/customScriptExtension",
     "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
     "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
     "dependsOn": "[az104-08-vm0]",
     "properties": {
         "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
         "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
         "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
         "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": $true,
         "settings": {
             "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools && powershell.exe remove-item 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\iisstart.htm' && powershell.exe Add-Content -Path 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\iisstart.htm' -Value $('Hello World from ' + $env:computername)"
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you using an arm template for deployment? @Tanmay Kanungo

Comment: try something like: `"powershell.exe -c 'Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools; 
\"Hello World from \" + $env:computername > C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\iisstart.htm"`

Comment: That is not a PowerShell script.  That is a JSON data file.   You can't execute that.

Comment: its a script extension, where you can specify the command and I'm suggesting a command that shall work for OP, not sure why would you mention that, tbh

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a sample template from this [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vm-simple-windows), modified the `VMExtensions` script as per your requirement and it worked as expected.

***Changes I made:***

- *I modified the* `dependsOn` *property to a* `single element` *array.*
- *The* `commandToExecute` *property is now separated commands with* `semicolons(;)` *rather than* `double ampersands (&&)`.
- *Changed* `autoUpgradeMinorVersion`  to ***"true"*** .

***Below is the modified script:***

```bash
{
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
"apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
"name": "xxxxx",
"location": "location",
"properties": {
"publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
"type": "CustomScriptExtension",
"typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
"autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
"settings": {
"commandToExecute": "powershell.exe Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools ; powershell.exe remove-item 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\iisstart.htm' ; powershell.exe Add-Content -Path 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\iisstart.htm' -Value $('Hello World from ' + $env:computername)"
     }
},
"dependsOn": [
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
 ]
}
```

*You can check the complete virtual machine sample template in the above referenced GitHub.*

***Deployed using below command and it was successful.***

```bash
az deployment group create --resource-group < RG > --template-file < filename > --parameters < filename>
```

[image]

[image]

Refer [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-deploy-vm-extensions.md) for more relevant information.